# model is not being updated in directive's click event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have following line of code.

**HTML**

```
...
<html ng-app="myApp">
....
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-model="info.myField"></div>
    <a href="#" my-update field="info.myField">Update Me</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]){
app.controller("myController", ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.info = {
        myField = "init value"
    };
}]);    

app.directive("myUpdate",function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope : {
            field:"="
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.field = "Updated in link";    //Line A

            elem.bind("click",function() {
                scope.field = "Updated on click";   //Line B
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I run this code, controller's info.myField is updated to "Updated in link" (as done in Directive's Line A). When I click "Update Me" anchor, Directive's Line B is executed but controller's info.myField is not updated.

Why info.myField is not being updated in click event? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to do like this,

```
elem.bind("click",function() {
           $scope.$apply({
              scope.field = "Updated on click";   //Line B
          });

 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Jayantha is correct, you should call `$apply()` to make it work. But you might ask why you should have to do that. The reason for this is that the `click` event happens outside of Angulars world. So Angular doesn't know that the `click` has happened, and you need to tell Angular about it, which you do by calling `scope.$apply()`. When you have a `ng-click` that calls a method on your scope, you don't have to call `$apply()` because it's Angular that calls that method for you, which means that Angular knows about it, and will call `$apply()` for you.

Comment: +1 for explaining answer. Alas, I am unable mark two answers as correct at the same time.